# cannot execute binary file exec format error windows bash

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, heroku

Am trying to deploy my node express app to heroku from my windows 10 os and am using the git bash terminal, but anytime i try to run the heroku command it returns this error

> '/c/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/heroku-cli/bin/run:
>   line 19: /c/Program Files/nodejs/node: cannot execute binary file:
>   Exec format error'

Please does anyone know how i could solve this challenge?

**PS: i ran the command as administrator on git bash**

Comment: What is in 19th line of run file?

Comment: I don't know, that's the heroku cli program

Comment: It should be a JS file. Just open it.

Comment: Ok, i just did and it's the following command: **cli.run()**

Comment: What you get if you just execute `node` in command line?

Comment: Wow, i just did and it gave me the following error: **Error 0xc1 starting node.exe** it's surprising because i have never gotten this error

Comment: Although i just upgraded node to version 8

Comment: Maybe you have a wrong architecture of NodeJS. I mean something like you have x64 system, but installed x32 Node or vice versa

Comment: Try to remove NodeJS and install it again. Be careful with selecting an architecture.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [heroku-cli GitHub repository](https://github.com/heroku/cli/blob/a4ba2b6d1e06406f26a1670a9bed4c3b054223fe/bin/run) I can see the following 19th line of the `run` file:

```
node "$DIR/run.js" "$@"
```

Looks like it tries to run `run.js` file but fails because can't recognise `node` as an executable binary file.

It's possible that you have a NodeJS version with wrong architecture or installation was not successful. Anyway seems like `node` is not installed correctly.

So I would uninstall it properly and install it again regarding  architecture of the OS